# Mongodb Views in spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, databricks

MongoDB provides support for the views from 3.4 version. How do I read the data from the views created in MongoDB in Apache Spark? I have tried treating the view as a regular collection in the `ReadConfig()`, and it is throwing the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 166: 'Namespace sample.<view_name> is a view, not a collection' on server <server>:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Namespace sample.<view_name> is a view, not a collection", "code" : 166, "codeName" : "CommandNotSupportedOnView" }
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer may have come a bit late, but I hope it can prove useful for someone. For reference, I'm working with Spark 2.3.0 and Scala 2.11.8.

As you noted, you can't treat a view like a collection and simply use a `ReadConfig()` with a uri, like the following:

```
// this does not work
val mongoRdd = spark.sparkContext
   .loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://appName:password@hosts/dbName.viewName")))
```

The `com.mongodb.MongoCommandException` you received appears to be the intended behavior for attempting this with a view, since the default partitioner utilizes the 'collstats' command, which is not available in views. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-193

Instead, you have to specify a partitioner in your `ReadConfig()`, like the following:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoSinglePartitioner

val customReadConfig = ReadConfig(
   databaseName = dbName,
   collectionName = viewName,
   connectionString = Option("mongodb://appName:password@hosts/dbName.viewName"),
   partitioner = MongoSinglePartitioner)

val mongoRdd = spark.sparkContext
   .loadFromMongoDB(customReadConfig)
```

The JIRA issue I linked proposes `MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner` and `MongoSinglePartitioner` as partitioning options for views.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might still be struggling with this.. I know I was. This is not a solution to the question but rather a workaround.

When following the documentation [Spark Connector Python Guide > Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/python/aggregation/)

Its seems that the pipeline stages can be stacked i.e:

```
stage1 = "{'$match': {'type': 'apple'}}"
stage2 = "{'$project': {'type': '$type'}}"
df = park.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("pipeline", 
stage1).option("pipeline",stage2).load()
df.show()
```

I've also tried to concatenate my stages into to a single pipeline variable:

```
pipeline = "{'$match': {'type': 'apple'}},{'$project': {'type': '$type'}}"
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("pipeline", 
pipeline).load()
df.show()
```

and also tried

```
pipeline = "{ {'$match': {'type': 'apple'}},{'$project': {'type': '$type'}} }"
```

but I kept on running into below exception so I ended up stacking the options

> org.bson.json.JsonParseException

Comment: This might be late, but don't you try the following - `pipeline = "[ {'$match': {'type': 'apple'}},{'$project': {'type': '$type'}} ]"`? MongoDB pipelines are the arrays of stages, and this is the representation of JSON array.

Comment: @Cerberus, no worries. Nice to get some feedback. You are correct but if I remember correctly I was in fact able to get it working using the array syntax when I used PyMongo and pandas from python interpreter  but not when I used spark.